# Confusion about zero-terminating character

Tags: c++

I've always had a question about null-terminated strings in C++/C. For example, if you have a character array like so:

```
char a[10];
```

And then you wanted to read in characters like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  cin >> a[i]; 
}
```

And lets in input the following word: questioner

as the input.

Now my question is what happens to the '\0'? If I were to reverse the string, and make it print out

```
renoitseuq
```

Where does the null-terminating character go? I thought that good programming practice was to always leave one extra character for the zero-terminating character. But in this example, everything was printed correctly, so why care about the null-terminating character? Just curious. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: `char a[10];` isn't null-terminated.

Comment: To add to Luchian Grigore's comment: the reason "everything was printed correctly" is that there *happens* to have been a null byte immediately after this character array, and that null byte got interpreted as the string terminator. But you obviously can't rely on that: there's no guarantee that the subsequent byte would be null.

Comment: Welcome to the territory of _undefined behavior_.

Comment: You shouldn't think of null-termination of having to do with *strings*. It is a detail of an *implementation of a string*. C has no native "string" type. The abstract idea of a string of characters is implemented in C as a null-terminated array of characters.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I wouldn't put it that way. A *string* in C is **by definition** "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character". Yes, C's "string" construct is one implementation of the abstract idea of "a string of characters". And C++ adds to the frivolity by defining the term *null-terminated byte string* for what C calls a *string*, and adding the `std::string` library class -- yet another implementation of the abstract idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where you're *given* a null-terminator, and cases where you have to ask for one yourself.

```
const char* x = "bla";
```

is a null-terminated C-style string. It actually has 4 characters - the 3 + the null terminator.

Your string isn't null-terminated. In fact, treating it as a null-terminated string leads to undefined behavior. If you were to `cout <<` it, you'd be attempting to read beyond the memory you're allowed to access, because the runtime will keep looking for a null-terminator and spit out characters until it reaches one. In your case, you were lucky there was one right at the end, but that's not a guarantee.

`char a[10];` is just like any other array - un-initialized values, 10 characters - not 11 just because it's a `char` array. You wouldn't expect `int b[10]` to contain 10 values for you to play with and an extra `0` at the end just because, would you?

Well, reading that back, I don't see why you'd expect that from a C-string as well - it's not all intuitive.

Comment: Hm, okay, so if I'm getting this correctly, we can add a '\0' to the end of our array but we do not have to. That '\0' will tell us if we are at the end of our character array. However, when we deal with c-style strings (meaning we deal with the string as a whole as opposed to characters with individual bytes like in the array I declared above or like in your example of *x = bla), or if we use c-style functions, then we'd have to account for the null terminating character?

Comment: @user200081 No, C does not have a string type. If you are doing C forget the type string. It's a figment of your over active imagination. Your choices are a fixed length array or a null terminated array. If you want an arbritary llimit for the length of your null terminated arrays, add 1 to it, and always set the last char to \0.

Comment: @user200081: The `'\0'` indicate the end of the (C-style) *string*, not necessarily the end of the character array. `a` is a 10-byte array. If it contains, for example, `"hello"`, then the `a[5]` is a `'\0'` character -- but there are still values stored in `a[6]` through `a[9]`. But if you're using it to store a C-style *string*, you'll probably ignore everything after the `'\0'`.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson okay, so basically what you're saying is that I can choose to have a null-terminated array or not? If I choose to have a null-terminated array, I have to add an extra character \0 for it? An example would be *x = "abc" and an implicit '\0' will be added because it is an arbitrary limit for the length. I can also do, in my example a[9] = '\0'; making it a null-terminated array then, correct?

Comment: Whe you are passing the array to a function, it will expect a length and the array as arguments, or if it only expects the array then it will "look" for the /0. Get them bum about face and you get problems. Have a look at the "string" libraries you've available. It's not hard to get, it's just hard to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 10 chars, not a string. I assume that you also output 10 chars in reverse, so the 0-char plays no role, coz you dont use the array as string, but as an array of single chars...

Answer (score 0):

`char a[10]` is ten characters, any of which can be a `'\0'`.
If you put `"questioner"` in there none of them are.
To get that you'd need `a[11]` and fill it with "questioner" and then `'\0'`.

If you were reversing it, you'd get the position of the first `'\0'` in a[?], reverse up to that and then add a null terminator.

This is a classic banana skin in C, unfortunately it still manages to get under your foot at the most inopportune of moments, even if you are all too familiar with it.